# How to center (keep center) a <div> or img when using transitions to adjust height and width.

Tags: html, css, transition

Okay.. so I'm a bit of newbie but not really.  Did a lot of html coding back in '04-06'.. decided to pick it up again.  Let me know if I don't make sense.  I have a client who wants a "lightbox" effect picture gallery for their pictures.  For example: when you click on a thumbnail a bigger picture zooms in while the background kind of fades out.  I decided to see if I could code it in css3 instead of resorting to javascript or whatnot.  I know this is probably impractical.. but the client doesn't have that many pictures and wants a fairly simple site.

Going smoothly for the most part.. except when it comes to bringing in the big picture.  I want this picture to come in centered on the page.. but something goofy happens when I transition from 0px to 400px.  It seems to grow to the right and bottom while the left and top stay put.  Any way to make this grow centered.  I know I could probably skip the width and height adjustment and use just the opacity transition.. but that doesn't look nearly as cool.

This is just the early stages so I haven't tested with other browsers.. and I know for a fact I need to add some more code for it to work in other browsers.. but I'm using chrome right now if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LIGHTBOX</title>
    <style>
            html{
                height:100%;
            }

            img{
                max-height:100%;
                max-width:100%;
            }

            .centerimage{
                    display:block;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    margin-right:auto;   
            }

    #imagezoom {
        position: absolute;
                    margin:-200 0 0 -200;
                    top:50%;
                    left:50%;
        z-index:-1;
                    padding-right:0;
                    border: solid 5px white;
        overflow: hidden;
                    width: 0px;
                    height: 0px;
                    opacity: .0;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 500px 50px #888888;
        transition: opacity .7s, width 1.5s, height 1.5s; 
    }

            #imagezoom:target{
                    z-index:2003;
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 400px;
        opacity: 1.0;
            }

</style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="imagezoom">
        <a href="file://localhost/Users/hollykrahulik/Desktop/
test%20website%20stuff/lightbox2.html">
        <img src="images/grumpycat.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>

<a href="#imagezoom">
        <img src="images/grumpycat_thumb.jpg" class="centerimage">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate what you're seeing in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed this `margin:-200 0 0 -200;` on `#imagezoom`.

Here's the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XheaK/embedded/result/)

Edit:
I assume you want this as output. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SpW5/)

```
#imagezoom:target{
    margin:-200px 0 0 -200px;
}
#imagezoom {
    transition: opacity .7s, margin 1.5s, width 1.5s, height 1.5s; 
}
```

Comment: Wow.. haha.. maybe I should thoroughly check my code before I ask for help.  Thanks!  That definitely helps.  I wonder if there is any way I can have it transition from all sides.. instead of staying put on upper left corner while the bottom and right sides expand.  Any idea?

Comment: @user2321962: Edited the answer. Have a look.

Comment: These solutions are so painfully obvious.. it makes me embarrassed!  Thanks for the help!